# I need to hook and change language of facebook sdk

Tags: filters, hooks

I need to hook into this function to change language to from en to french facebook sdk.

```
$facebook_sdk_src = apply_filters( 'bimber_facebook_sdk_src', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5' );
```

So I only need to change this url on second, and I need to add or apply some filter. So how can I change this url part `//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5`

Comment: You mean you want to sue `add_filter()` ?

Comment: Yes I want to add_filter so I can change this url part, do you have an idea?

Comment: Then simply do `add_filter('bimber_facebook_sdk_src', 'your_callback_function');` and in your callback function do what you want.

Comment: So can I just have ` somefunction(){

return url-i-need-for-sdk

}`

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation of [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) first argument is name of filter and second one is callback function name. (both are required)

See the example for your case:-

```
add_filter('bimber_facebook_sdk_src', 'change_fb_sdk_url');
function change_fb_sdk_url($current_url) {
    // Variable $current_url hold the current value of URL
    // You can manipulate what you want
    // Or simply return your URL

    return '//url_you_want';
}
```

Please note:- filter callback function must return the value!

Comment: Thank you, this works. I made the same but I forgot to put a variable inside function, why it is important and can it be any name, you said it holds the current value of url but where it is fetching it from?

Comment: you are welcome! What you made will work as well. I put the variable just for your understanding. It is not necessary if you are not using it and yes it can be any name. This is how it work, we pass value to `apply_filter()` and it pass the value to all `add_filter()`, `add_filter` manipulate this value and return back to `apply_filter`. I hope it helps you!

Comment: Yeah I understand it now, you really helped I appreciate that. I was making also mistake by saying `apply_filter` in functions.php first time instead of `add_filter`. Anyway thank you on explanations :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Cheers :)